# How to reset only the young drivers test mode in F1 2012?

Tags: ps3, f1-2012

Is it possible to only reset the Young Drivers Test mode in F1 2012 (PS3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought so as the Young Drivers Test is saved within the same Profile Data on the Saved Game Data utility.
So while you can reset the mode and start again, this will also reset your Career, Time Attack, and Champions Mode statistics. Which you probably already know.

Sorry!